# Can Sass select element by postion?

Tags: css, sass

There is a table, and there is no `id` with `td`

```
<table id='mytable'>
   <tr>
     <td>
         I want to right without id 
     </td>

     <td>
         I want to left without id
     </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How to make the content of the first `td` align right and the second align left ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, You can do it by CSS.

Use this:

```
table tr td:nth-child(1){
}
table tr td:nth-child(2){
}
```

Like many more. Here is the reference site.

1. [nth-child](http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/).
2. [evenodd](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html).

Answer (score 1):

With CSS, you use:

[:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anth-child)

```
td:nth-child(an+b)
```

- a is the rate (or slope), or where 1 = every element, 2 = every other element, 3 = every third element, and soforth.
- n is a constant. it's literally n. just n. and it's only used when you use a.
- b is the initial position (or y-intercept) of the child selector. meaning + 1 would start at the first element found, +3 would be the third... b cannot be negative nor zero.

**BUT**, this method doesn't work with IE8 (as CSS3 psuedoclasses aren't supported =< IE8), so, if you're supporting IE8, you could use a little bit of jQuery... or try something like [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/), which uses a js shim to prop IE6-8 up with CSS3 selectors like nth-child.

The other thing that you could do is just give each row even/odd classes (or column-xyz-1, column-xyz-2, etc), and style it that way... as that gives you equal flexibility to manage styles...

Answer (score 0):

I see that you only have two elements to work with.

In addition to the already mentioned `nth-child` pseudo-class, you can use the `+` adjacent sibling combinator:

```
td {
  /* Styles for the first element */
}

td + td {
  /* Styles for all elements except the first*/
  text-align: right;
}
```

This combinator is supported by IE starting with version 7!